# Правильно ли стоит тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение такое: "И вообще, я так считаю — если уж ты болеешь, так можешь хотя бы порадовать себя стаканчиком любимого напитка". Правильно ли тут поставлено тире перед "если"?

Answer (score 1):

Теоретически здесь должно быть двоеточие, т. к. дальше идёт пояснение (можно подставить фразу "а именно").